# Change data in std::vector inside const context

Tags: c++11, stl

It there a way to change the data stored inside a std::vector inside a const function? See the following code to understand what I want to accomplish:

```
// class holding properties and data
class Output{
public:
    int * values; // possibility 1: raw pointer
    std::vector<int> vc; // possibility 2: std::vector
    mutable std::vector<int> vm;  // possibility 3: mutable vector
    //std::vector<mutable int> vm; something like this,        
};
class Node{
   Output out;
   void test()const{
       // i want to change the "data" of the Output but not the Object 
       out.values[0] = 0;//works: i can change the output data
       out.values = nullptr;//works: compile error, i cant change the pointer
       out.vc[0] = 1; // compile error, not possible :(
       out.vm[0] = 1; // that is what i want
       out.vm.resize(3); // this is now possible, but should be not possible
   }
};
```

I can use a raw pointer to achieve my goal, but i would prefer a std::vector if this is possible.

A mutable content vector may looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class mutable_vector : public std::vector<T>{
public:
    T& operator[](int index)const{
        return const_cast<mutable_vector<T>*>(this)->data()[index];
    }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin()const{
        return const_cast<mutable_vector<T>*>(this)->begin();
    }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator rbegin()const{
        return const_cast<mutable_vector<T>*>(this)->rbegin();
    }
};
```

Comment: You are already using `mutable` which has exactly this purpose. What are you exactly trying to achieve? Making a member variable *partially* non-`const` so that you can change the content but not resize it? This sounds more a design flaw.

Comment: Yes, I should be only possible to change the content of the vector, but not the vector itself(like resizing, reserve, inserting, erasing) like in the raw pointer version, where you can change the data where the pointer points to but not the pointer itself(you cant set the pointer to a different address, ...)

Comment: I have Nodes that compute something and writing the result to Outputs, the Nodes should not change the Output Objects and their properties but should be able the write to the buffer in the output object

Comment: Make the vector private, provide an accessor method returning `int*`, have it return `vm.data()`

Comment: I think this is the best solution if you dont want to rewrite std::vector